# How to stop calling action/actionListener/onclick/oncomplete while page is refresh

Tags: jsf

While page is reload, keep calling action method.

I only want to call this action method when link is clicked.

```
<li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="ViewAMC.xhtml" action="#       {treeTableManagedBean.testingActionListener()}" >View AMC</a>
</li>

public void testingActionListener()
{
    System.out.println("testing action listener!");
    flag = false;
}
```

Comment: Where did you learn you can add an `action` like this to a plain `<a>` tag like this? This is just not supported and the duplicates of 'why is this action called on page load all apply here.

Comment: so, which one should i use for that

Comment: i want to call this method when this link is click, but keep calling this method while page is reload.

Comment: You may have a look at `<f:viewAction`.

Comment: ok, i'll try it. :)

Comment: @Holger: OP does **not** want the method to be called on pageload

Comment: i'm totally confused now. <f:viewAction is always work on page load.

Comment: I only want to call my method on my button link is clicked.

Comment: That is why I commented. Using `f:viewAction` was a wrong suggestion. @Holger misinterpreted the question I think. The duplicate contains the right answer and explanation. The answer below is 'right' as well, but lacks detail and should not be accepted in my opinion

Comment: i learn and tried from duplicate question, but still have problem. I cannot redirect my target page and still reload in current page. I tried like that return "/ViewAMC?faces-redirect=true";

Comment: I just started learn about jsf. how to redirect my target page. this page is under 'WebContent/JSF/ViewAMC.xhtml'.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandLink action="#{treeTableManagedBean.testingAction()}"  value="Click Here" actionListener="#{treeTableManagedBean.myActionListener}">


    public void myActionListener(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("testing action listener!");
    }


    public String testingAction() {
        System.out.println("testing action !");
        return "ViewAMC.xhtml";
    }
```

Try this out.

Comment: ok, i'll try it. :)

Comment: cannot redirect mypage like that.

Comment: While this may answer the question, it is 1: Better to search if duplicates of something exist and refer to those. 2: Add some explanation on why this code is better then the original code.